# ServiceStack FluentValidation - Issue with Multiple RuleSets

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I have a validator with two RuleSets.  The first RuleSet has 4 rules and the second has 2 rules.  When I call Validate with each RuleSet individually, I get the correct number of errors (4 and 2) but when I call them together, I get NO errors...  For the life of me, I can't figure out why - any help appreciated!

(Note: In all cases, the 6 properties being tested are set to null...)

Validator:

```
public class ClientValidator : AbstractValidator<Client> {
    public ClientValidator() {
        RuleSet("RequiredHomeValidations", () => {
            RuleFor(client => client.Street)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Client's street address is required.");
            RuleFor(client => client.City)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Client's city is required.");
            RuleFor(client => client.State)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Client's state is required.");
            RuleFor(client => client.ZipCode)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Client's ZIP Code is required.");
        });

        RuleSet("RequiredContactsValidations", () => {
            RuleFor(client => client.PrimaryContactFirstName)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("First name of client's primary contact is required.");
            RuleFor(client => client.PrimaryContactLastName)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Last name of client's primary contact is required.");
        });
```

Calls to Validate:

```
        //ValidationResult requiredFieldsValidationResult = this.ClientValidator.Validate(client, ruleSet: "RequiredHomeValidations");  <-- 4 ERRORS
        //ValidationResult requiredFieldsValidationResult = this.ClientValidator.Validate(client, ruleSet: "RequiredContactsValidations");  <-- 2 ERRORS
        ValidationResult requiredFieldsValidationResult = this.ClientValidator.Validate(client, ruleSet: "RequiredHomeValidations, RequiredContactsValidations");  <-- 0 ERRORS, .IsValid == true
```

Answer (score 1):

This was due to ServiceStack's interned version of FluentValidation being based on an earlier version that didn't support multiple result sets.

This should now be resolved in the latest **v4.0.41+** of ServiceStack that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: I was hoping it was something like that.  Thanks again for the great product and great support!

Comment: mythz - is there a limit on the number of rule sets allowed?  I now have 4 rule sets - A, B, C, and D.  In my test case, A produces two errors and C produces one.  B and D produce none.  When I run them all together, I get only the two errors from A.  When I run A and B I get the two from A and when I run C and D, I get the one from C.  Not sure why I don't get all three when I run them all together?

Comment: @user2220004 What behavior does the normal [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) library have?

Comment: I used version 5.6.2 from NuGet and that seemed to have an issue with just 2 RuleSets together.  Individually I got the correct number of errors from each, together, I just got the ones from the first RuleSet in the list.  What version is included in your 4.0.41+ ?